# External fonts not available on XIB

Tags: ios4

Hey friends, I've added a font file (.ttf) in resources folder in XCode 4 and also in info.plist. I am able to use those fonts via code. But those fonts are not available on XIB i.e. font name appears in the list but its not getting applied onto UI components (some default font style gets applied). Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3):

I found that we've to create IBOutlet for components whose font style we want to change.

Custom fonts does appear when we edit text in xib, but they don't get applied at runtime.